# Setting Nested Attributes of an existing record based on specific parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My first post here so I hope I'm including all the necessary information!  Happy I've managed to make it two months into learning without having to ask any questions yet. :-)

I have a Callsheets record with a nested Store record that contains a :lastvisit column that I would like to update each time a new Callsheet is submitted every month.  The :lastvisit field should be updated where the Store :id == @callsheet.store_id which is already defined.   The beginner in me thinks the correct code for the 'update' method would be

```
@callsheet.update(callsheet_params).where(@callsheet.store_id => @store.id)
```

but I'm not sure how to access @store in this instance, and this likely just creates a new record anyways.

Any help or points in the right direction are appreciated.  Thanks!

I've been trying to get it running in the 'update' method, but would also like to get it running in the 'create' method if that's any different.  Relevant info:

callsheet.rb:

```
class Callsheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store
```

callsheets_controller.rb:

```
class CallsheetsController < ApplicationController

def update
@callsheet = Callsheet.find(params[:id])
    if @callsheet.update(callsheet_params)
      redirect_to callsheet_dashboard_path
    else
      render action: :edit
    end
end

def callsheet_params
  params.require(:callsheet).permit(:id, :user_id, :store_id, . . . , store_attributes: [:id, :lastvisit])
```

edit.html.erb:

```
      <%= form_for @callsheet, url: callsheet_path, remote: true, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :store do |s| %>
            <%= s.text_field :lastvisit, :id => 'lastvisitHidden' %>
          <% end %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :store_id, :id => 'storeSelectHidden' %>
```

//

Comment: Remove `:id` from nested_attributes, it should be `store_attributes: [:lastvisit]`

Comment: You can't chain `where` on `@callsheet.update`, nor `@callsheet`. Only the `Callsheet` model or another query (`where`, `all`, `order`, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `store_id` column on `callsheet` that's called a "foreign key", and you can write these associations on the models:

```
#callsheet
belongs_to :store

#store
has_many :callsheets
```

Then in your controller action, after `@callsheet.update(callsheet_params)`:

```
  @callsheet.store.update(last_visit: Time.now)
```

This is simplest, and is what I'd recommend. `@callsheet.store` returns a store *instance* (you always need to keep track of whether your variables are model instances, model queries, or arrays.)

You could alternatively say this, it's just showing another way to access the store:

```
 Store.find_by(id: @callsheet.store_id).update(last_visit: Time.now)
```

`find_by` is known as a "query method" (see [ActiveRecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)), but unlike most of the others it returns an instance and not a query. `update` is only callable on instances, and returns a boolean indicating whether the save was succesful. `update` also triggers the callback chain - see [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Another way to do it:

```
Store.where(id: @callsheet.store_id).update_all(last_visit: Time.now)
```

This uses the `.where` query method, which returns a query (in this case you know it will be one element), and then the `update all` query method (which does not trigger the callback chain).

The last is kind of confusing and I'd dissuade you from using it. The reason being that a callsheet has only a single store, so loading it as an array is misleading.

Comment: Thank you!  You also managed to answer about another 5 questions I would have likely had in the future regarding Active Record.  The Store.find_by method is what I ended up using.  One question though, the "belongs_to :store_id" line didn't work, while "belongs_to :store" did.  Is :store_id in this instance referring to Store.id or Callsheet.store_id?